# How can I assign value to a string "char by char" after declaration in c?

Tags: c, string, cs50

```
int main(void)
{
   string original = "ABCdef";
   string upper;
   string lower;
   
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      if (isupper(original[i]) > 0)
      {
         upper[i]= original[i] - 32;
      }
      else
      {
         upper[i] = original[i];
      }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      if (islower(key[i]) > 0)
      {
         lower_key[i] = key[i] + 32;
      }
      else
      {
         lower_key[i] = key[i];
      }
   }
}
```

My goal here is to create 2 new strings, upper and lower, that are the uppercase and lowercase versions of original to be used later in my program. When I run the program as it is above the IDE tells me that I must assign upper and lower values before using them.

I have tried assigning NULL to them both at initialisation, as the IDE suggests, but this resulted in an error. When that failed, I tried assigning original to both. This almost worked, but for some reason meant that all three variables were altered when I assigned upper and lower different values within the if functions. This is a problem, as I need to be able to use upper and lower separately later on. Finally, I tried assigning "ABCDEF" to them both, but of course ran into the issue of an "incompatible pointer to integer assigning to 'string'" error.

How should I declare upper and lower in order for them to work as intended?

Comment: The `string` type is a CS50 (mis)feature — include the tag (I've added it) to avoid criticism.

Comment: Your `string upper;` etc have not been initialised – they don't point anywhere valid, so `upper[i]= original[i] - 32;` is going to fail.

Comment: @WeatherVane right, this is what I was trying to get at. I will edit my post to be more clear. How should I initialise them in order to avoid the errors I described?

Comment: You can use `malloc()` or (if the compiler supports it) use `string upper = strdup(original)` which itself uses `malloc()`. Don't for get to allow room for the string terminator.

Comment: But then, your upper/lower-casing logic is faulty (your conversion is inconsistent with the check), and relies on a specific character coding. Use `upper[i] = toupper(original[i]);`